# How to export the left and right channels of a very large wave/audio file (400meg/22+mins) as an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, vector-graphics, audacity

How to export the left and right channels of a very large wave/audio file (400meg/22+mins) as an image (the best format maybe a vector image format) See wave file image below. I'm trying to superimpose the Left and right channels on top of each other to get a graphic.

I know I can do a screenshot but there's no way to get a 22+min sound file zoomed in to fit on one screen.  Is there a way to export each  channel zoomed in as vector art?

[image]

Comment: @A.Donda I tried screenshots.

Comment: Try reading in the audio file using `audioread`.  It'll give you a 2D matrix where each column denotes the audio from each channel.  After this, try plotting each channel using `plot`, then use the figure menu and save this plot as a `.eps` file. I've never dealt with such a large audio file before so you may have to fragment up the file into multiple parts, then do this separately for each part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GNU Octave you can do

```
[Y, FS, BPS] = wavread ("out2.wav");
samples = rows (Y);
# Plot 0.2s blocks
len_seconds = 0.2;
blocksize = FS * len_seconds;
numblocks = floor (samples / blocksize);
for k=0:numblocks;
  idx_start = k * blocksize+1;
  idx_stop  = (k+1) * blocksize;
  t = linspace ((idx_start-1) / FS, idx_stop / FS, blocksize);
  plot (t, Y(idx_start:idx_stop, :))
  grid on
  xlabel ("time [s]");
  print ("-dpdf", sprintf ("waveplot%i.pdf", k));
endfor
```

which reads the entire wav and plots blocks which are 0.2s long. I've attached the first generated output (converted to png):

[image: First block]

If your PC has low memory (<8GB) I suggest reading the wav in chunks and process them separately, see "help wavread": [...] = wavread (FILENAME, [N1 N2]). You should also consider that the generated graphical plots needs much more space on the hardrive, I guess factor 5..20 dependent on your image format.

Comment: @Rick T: Do you need any further assistance?